# extend Uint8Array then map gives wrong result

Tags: javascript

Why does `hex()` implementation do not work as expected but the `hex2()` works fine.

```js
class Bytes extends Uint8Array {
  hex() {
    return this.map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join('');
  }

  hex2() {
    return [...this].map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join('');
  }
}

const a = new Bytes([1, 2, 30]);
console.log(a.hex());  // 120
console.log(a.hex2()); // 01021e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All "legit" `.map` methods will return an object of the same interface than the one on which it exists.

So on a TypedArray, it will return a TypedArray.

```js
const arr = new Uint8Array();
console.log( arr.map( () => {} ) instanceof Uint8Array );
```

But a TypedArray can't hold Strings, only numbers, and for the Uint8Array Typed Array, only integer numbers in the range 0 to 255.
So `Uint8Array.map( fnThatReturnsStrings )` will try to cast all the return values to numbers in that range.

`"01"` => `1`
`"02"` => `2`
`"1e"` =>  `NaN` => `0`

Comment: Interesting to know.

Comment: Very interesting to know, especially after being bitten by it. Given that map - outside of the bitflipping realm of Buffers Uint8Arrays etc - is often used to map one element "type" to another, for example in connection with mapped sorting, this was a bit surprising.